# Binary subsets for a given set

Tags: sets, binary, computer-algebra

Lets take an example of the range of N=32 bits

```
2^32 = 4294967296

00000000000000000000000000000000
00000000000000000000000000000001
00000000000000000000000000000010
00000000000000000000000000000011
...
11111111111111111111111111111100
11111111111111111111111111111101
11111111111111111111111111111110
11111111111111111111111111111111
```

Now lets consider a subset within this range whose consecutive 0s can be 0 to maximum 3 0s.

The following are examples of valid and invalid subsets -

Valid subset (consecutive 0s - 0 to maximum 3):

```
00100100100100100100100100100101 - (subset 0)
10101010101010101010101010101010 - (subset 1)
10010010010010001000100010101111 - (subset 2)
11011001000111101000100010010011 - (subset 3)
...
11111111111111111111111111111111 - (subset S max value)
```

So, count(valid subset) < 2^32

Invalid subset (at least 1 consecutive 0s > 3):

```
10000111111111111111111111111001
10101010100000000001111000100111
11111111101010101010101010000001
10000000000000001111010100010101
...
```

I have the following queries -

1. How to find the total count of valid subsets for a given value of N (ex. 2^32, 2^40, 2^64 etc)
2. How to dynamically generate the subset value for each matching subset, in an incremental manner, for a given value of N (ex. 2^32, 2^40, 2^64 etc)

So, for N=32,

```
If the value is "00100100100100100100100100100101", then subset value "0" must be dynamically generated
If the value is "10101010101010101010101010101010", then subset value "1" must be dynamically generated
If the value is "10010010010010001000100010101111", then subset value "2" must be dynamically generated
If the value is "11011001000111101000100010010011", then subset value "3" must be dynamically generated
If the value is "11111111111111111111111111111111", then subset value "subset S max" must be dynamically generated
```

3. Consecutively, given the subset value, the bit value must also be
   dynamically generated

So, for N=32,

```
If subset value is "0", then bit value "00100100100100100100100100100101" must be dynamically generated
If subset value is "subset S max", then bit value "11111111111111111111111111111111" must be dynamically generated
```

and so on...

The main point is *dynamically generating the values*, so they are not required to be stored; this is feasible for large values of N (ex. 2^32, 2^40, 2^64 etc and greater)

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.  I see three different questions here, which will have different techniques. If you have 3 questions, you can post them separately.  I suggest you [edit] this post to focus on one of the three questions and remove the other 2, and post the other 2 separately.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/74763694/781723

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/156316/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4602470/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 2):

Let $A(n,k)$ denote the number of valid strings of length $n$ ending with a string of $k$ zeroes. Then:

- $A(0,0) = 1$
- $A(0,1) = A(0,2) = A(0,3) = 0$
- $A(n+1,0) = A(n,0) + A(n,1) + A(n,2) + A(n,3)$
- $A(n+1,k+1) = A(n,k)$

You are interested in $A(n,0) + A(n,1) + A(n,2) + A(n,3)$ for various values of $n$.

Using these formulas, it is routine to implement ranking and unranking, that is, to convert a valid string to its index in the list of all valid strings, ordered lexicographically (ranking) and vice versa (unranking).

---

With slightly more effort, we can obtain a direct recurrence formula for $B(n) = A(n,0) + A(n,1) + A(n,2) + A(n,3)$:
$$
B(n) = B(n-1) + B(n-2) + B(n-3) + B(n-4)
$$
with initial values $B(0),B(1),B(2),B(3) = 1,2,4,8$.