# Order in a subset

Tags: combinatorics, sets, arithmetic, binary

Lets consider a range of "K" binary digit numbers. In that range, we want to take a subset of those values which have (<="n" consecutive 0s) AND (<="n" consecutive 1s).

Then, we want to find the order of values in the resulting subset incrementally.

Also, we want to do the "un-ordering" of the values. i.e. find the value of the subset from the given order.

Note: The order must be found only by checking the subset value, and not by trying to iterate all values upto that value. This will be efficient for a large "K" range of digits.

Example:

> K = 6

> n <= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s

```
000000 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
000001 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
000010 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
000011 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
000100 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
000101 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
000110 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
000111 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
001000 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
001001 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [1]
001010 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [2]
001011 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [3]
001100 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [4]
001101 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [5]
001110 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
001111 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset

010000 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
010001 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
010010 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [6]
010011 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [7]
010100 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [8]
010101 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [9]
010110 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [10]
010111 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
011000 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
011001 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [11]
011010 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [12]
011011 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [13]
011100 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
011101 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
011110 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
011111 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset

100000 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
100001 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
100010 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
100011 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
100100 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [14]
100101 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [15]
100110 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [16]
100111 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
101000 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
101001 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [17]
101010 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [18]
101011 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [19]
101100 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [20]
101101 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [21]
101110 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
101111 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset

110000 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
110001 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
110010 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [22]
110011 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [23]
110100 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [24]
110101 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [25]
110110 -> (<= 2 consecutive 0s AND 1s) -> order [26]
110111 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
111000 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
111001 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
111010 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
111011 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
111100 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
111101 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
111110 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
111111 -> (>2 consecutive 0s OR 1s) -> remove from subset
```

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/162157/755, https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/53333/5038, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4772556/14578, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/447688/34181.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  You were [previously asked not to cross-posted](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/156316/binary-subsets-for-a-given-set#comment328866_156316).  Please take note this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are known as ranking and unranking algorithms.  See, e.g., https://computationalcombinatorics.wordpress.com/2012/09/10/ranking-and-unranking-of-combinations-and-permutations/

Let $\text{rank}(x)$ denote the rank of $x \in \{0,1\}^K$, i.e., the number of $K$-bit strings that lexicographically precede $x$ and satisfy your requirements (no more than $n$ consecutive 0's or 1's).

Define $f_{K,n}(w)$ as the number of $K$-bit strings that start with $w$ and that satisfy your requirements (no more than $n$ consecutive 0's or 1's).  $f_{K,n}(w)$ can be computed in polynomial time by forming a DFA for the regular language of $K$-bit strings that start with $w$ and satisfy your requirements, and then counting the number of strings accepted by this DFA.  (See https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/8200/5038 and https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/71379/755.)

$\text{rank}(x)$ can be expressed as a sum of at most $K$ terms of the form $f_{K,n}(w)$.  Specifically,

$$\text{rank}(x) = \sum_{i=1}^K x_i f_{K,n}(x_{1 \cdots i-1} 0).$$

By the above remarks, this gives a polynomial-time algorithm for computing $\text{rank}(x)$.

Let $\text{unrank}(n)$ denote the unranking of $n \in \mathbb{N}$, i.e., the string $x$ such that $\text{rank}(x)=n$. You can obtain an algorithm for computing $\text{unrank}(n)$ in polynomial time, using filling in one bit of $x$ at a time and calling $\text{rank}(\cdot)$ at each step.  For instance, if $\text{rank}(100\cdots 0) > n$, then $x$ starts with 0, otherwise $x$ starts with $1$; and so on.